# How to instantiate this class parametrized by bonded interface?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I've got 3 interfaces:

```
public interface IAggregable<TElement extends IAggregable<TElement, TResult>, TResult> {
    TResult aggregate(TResult intermediateResult);
}

public interface IDeeplyCloneable<TElement extends IDeeplyCloneable<TElement>> {
    TElement deepClone();
}
public interface IContainer<TElement extends IAggregable<TElement, TResult> & IDeeplyCloneable<TElement>, TResult> {
    TResult aggregateAllElements();
    TElement cloneElementAtIndex(int index);
}
```

Then there are two classes that implement those 2 first interfaces:

```
public class Person implements IAggregable<Person, Integer>, IDeeplyCloneable<Person> {
    private int age;

    public Integer aggregate(Integer intermediateResult) {
        if (intermediateResult == null) {
            return age;
        }
        return age + intermediateResult;
    }

    public Person deepClone() {
        Person clone = new Person();
        clone.age = age;
        return clone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [age=" + age + "]";
    }

}
```

and almost exactly the same

```
 public class Car implements IAggregable<Car, Integer>, IDeeplyCloneable<Car> {

    private int horsepower;

    public Integer aggregate(Integer intermediateResult) {
        if (intermediateResult == null) {
            return horsepower;
        }
        return horsepower + intermediateResult;
    }

    public Car deepClone() {
        Car clone = new Car();
        clone.horsepower = horsepower;
        return clone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car [horsepower=" + horsepower + "]";
    }

}
```

then there's finally `UselessContainer` which suppose to implement `IContainer` and  be able to hold both `Person` and `Car` and any other objects of any other class that implements `IAggregable` and `IDeeplyCloneable`.

```
public class UselessContainer<TElement extends IAggregable<TElement, TResult> & IDeeplyCloneable<TElement>, TResult> implements IContainer<TElement, TResult> {

    private ArrayList<TElement> list;

    public UselessContainer() {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(TElement element) {
        list.add(element);
    }

    @Override
    public TResult aggregateAllElements() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public TElement cloneElementAtIndex(int index) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return list.toString();
    }

}
```

**Question** : How to create object of class `UselessContainer`?

I've tried that: `UselessContainer<? extends IAggregable<?, Integer> & IDeeplyCloneable<?>, Integer> container;`

Comment: Try `UselessContainer<Person, Integer> container;` or `UselessContainer<Car, Integer> container;`! If you want to place different classes in the same container, then your interface design is wrong.

Comment: @fabian this is something that I don't want i want to be able to hold both Car and Person in the same container.

Answer (score 0):

You have marked your `UselessContainer` to be bound BOTH to IAggregable and IDeeplyCloneable. Please look at the `&` sign which indicates both of the interfaces must be implemented by business entity to be added to the list.

In order to use it in code - just create instance of `UselessContainer` without specyfing concrete generics types:

```
   UselessContainer uc = new UselessContainer();
    uc.add(new Person()); // works!
    uc.add(new Integer(1)); // won't compile
    uc.add(new Car()); // works!
```

I just tried it in my Editor and it works (JDK8).

*EDIT:*
You may create wrapping class:

```
class SimpleContainer {
    public <TElement extends IAggregable<TElement, TResult> & IDeeplyCloneable<TElement>, TResult> void add(TElement el) {
        UselessContainer<TElement, TResult> uc = new UselessContainer<>();
        uc.add(el);
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
   SimpleContainer sc = new SimpleContainer();
        sc.add(new Person());
```

Comment: I've done that already and it worked fine, but I wanted to explicitely parametrize `UselessContainer`.

Comment: The only thing I have in mind is to create wrapping class with method, I edited my answer above ^. What explicit parameters would give to the container? What is the business case ?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 conditions you want to meet for `UselessContainer<A, B>` (well shorten this to `U<A,B>`):

(1) `Car`s can be added to `U<A, B>`

(2) `Person`s can be added to `U<A, B>`

Fulfilling both (1) and (2) is impossible, which can be proven using a indirect proof:

Assume fulfilling both conditions was possible.

The signature of `add` is `add(TElement element)` method and `TElement extends IAggregable<TElement, TResult>`.

From (1) and `Car implements IAggregable<Car, Integer>` we can therefore deduce `A=Car`.

And from (2) and `Person implements IAggregable<Person, Integer>` we can therefore deduce `A=Person`.

Combining those 2 results we get `Car=Person` which is obviously wrong. This contradiction concludes the proof.

---

This means you have to modify the restrictions on the type parameters or use the raw type.